# Getting the count of the total View objects on all Post objects for a User object

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

My application has View objects attached to Post objects (many to one). A User object hasMany Posts. How do I retrieve essentially `$totalViews = $user->posts()->views()->count();`?

That syntax obviously doesn't work. I could loop through each $user->posts and add up the views, but that seems really slow and there's probably a better way.

Comment: what about eager loading?

Comment: @PeteHouston that would prevent a n+1 query when looping through each post, but it's still having to loop through each Post which is possibly slow.

Comment: is there any error if `$user->posts->views->count()`?

Comment: @PeteHouston Yes, $user->posts returns a collection which doesn't have a `views` attribute. `PHP error:  Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$views on line 1`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to retrieve?  The number of posts a user has made in a single view?

Comment: @user3158900 I am trying to retrieve the total number of times a Post has been viewed across all Posts for a single User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to do it with Eloquent relationships, but you can do it in 2 steps.

```
$arrayOfIds = Post::where('user_id', $id)->get('id')->toArray();
$totalViews = View::whereIn('post_id', $arrayOfIds)->count();
```

that's probably the simplest way I can think of doing it.

Comment: For anyone else who may want it, I would up using `$posts = DB::table('posts')->where('user_id', 1)->lists('id');` to get the array of post IDs since this returns just an array of integers rather than an array of objects